# how to solve android b.a.a.b timeout error?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp

I have an `android` app that connect to backend with `okhttp` and `retrofit` to get the data via `api` from the backend. The login process will takes quite a lot datas on the backend. However some users encountered `b.a.a.b` error. What is `b.a.a.b` on `Android` terms as I can be considered as novice on android. image as follow

or the error is

```
mulaiLogin() || ERROR: b.a.a.b: HTTP 504 Connection Timed Out
```

Here is the retrofit and okhttp builder code

```
 final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
          .readTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .connectTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
          .build();

 retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
          .baseUrl(BuildConfig.JariBaseURL)
          .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
          .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
          .client(okHttpClient)
          .build();
```

While the login process is like this, I am using rxjava

```
 addSubscribe(apiStores.userLogin(body), new NetworkCallback<LoginResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResponse response) {
            MyLocalDB.setAPILogTable(activity.getApplicationContext(), "Login", gson.toJson(body),
                    response.getCode(), response.getDesc(), MyMethods.GenerateRef(new Date()),
                    "-");
            switch (response.getCode()) {....and so on
```

This error happened for some users (field team). They cannot login (completing the `API Login`) while most user can login successfully.

I tried to enlarge the `timeout` size and set `retryOnConnectionFailure(false)` on `okhttp` but it seems does not solve the problem

**EDIT: So after tracking the obfuscate, b.a.a.b is retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.HttpException**

Comment: b.a.a.b sounds like the shortened java package that your exception is occurring in.

Comment: I suspect that `b.a.a.b` is the name of the class that logs the message after obfuscation. Check the build logs of the build to see how your classes where renamed and which class ended up with that name. Then continue debugging from there.

Comment: @JoachimSauer how to check the build logs? I can't find any b.a.a.b on build window and clicking the icon below the green hammer (on build window)

Comment: Is this a signed apk log? If so, use your `mapping.txt` file (generated after you signed build your apk) to map back to the class and functions responsible for this.

Comment: Is this signed apk that you are testing? If yes, post your `build.gradle` and proguard rules file.

Comment: EDIT: so after tracking, b.a.a.b is retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.HttpException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enable `minifyEnabled` on your release build Android employs a tool named Proguard to obfuscated your classes. This makes them harder for an attacker to understand when they are de-compiled. Proguard takes your class names, variables and others and changes them. For example **MyNiceClass** becomes **a** or something equally odd looking. You can track the changes using the mapping.txt found in app/build/outputs/mapping/appname/release.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code

You have a few options

1) Use your mapping.txt file and try and figure out what classes are being talked about (not much fun).

2) Try and [re-build your stacktrace](https://medium.com/@maheshwar.ligade/de-obfuscate-stack-traces-6e19a52a3379) (if you have it):

3) Use a tool like [Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/) (owned by Firebase) where you upload your mapping.txt file and it will re-construct your full stack trace for easy reading.

So the short answer is no one really knows what b.a.a.b stands for.

**Your problem:**

That said it looks pretty straightforward that your app is experiencing timeouts. You have done the right thing increasing the timeout delay, however at some point the delay becomes too long for a user to wait.

Do you check the user has an internet connection before starting a network request?

You mention users in a field team, there is a big difference in testing on a solid wifi connection and out in the field on a mobile signal. You should run some tests on your app on a very slow connection and see how it performs. You may want to consider smaller data packets or optimising your server response.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of obfuscation, I found that b.a.a.b is retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.HttpException. So it is more like the problem on the API? or I can increase the timeout on rxjava things?